# Generating a primary key unique across multiple databases

Tags: sql, etl, data-warehouse

Operational databases of identical structure work in several countries.

```
country A has table Users with column user_id
country B has table Users with column user_id
country C has table Users with column user_id
```

When data from all three databases is brought to the staging area for the further data warehousing purposes all three operational tables are integrated into a single table Users with dwh_user_id.

The logic looks like following:

```
if record comes from A then dwh_user_id = 1000000 + user_id
if record comes from B then dwh_user_id = 4000000 + user_id
if record comes from c then dwh_user_id = 8000000 + user_id
```

I have a strong feeling that it is a very bad approach. What would be a better approach? 
(user_id + country_iso_code maybe?)

Comment: I would add two columns: country, and a new unique id.

Comment: what you are talking about is Master Data Management. The `CountryCode + to_char(user_id)' is a way to do it. Although there are multiple opinion about using string primary key.  The other way is that you can use a surrogate key as DWH_USER_ID and add 2 columns, one for country code and 1 for user_id.

Comment: Any fixed-length key will have this feeling that the allotted range will not be enough and the records will overflow to the next range. You decide if that is a possibility in your database, and if it is, you either increase the ranges until it feels good or come up with a variable-length key with delimiters.

Comment: Yes it's a bad approach. If you already have a datawarehouse then you should already have generated two new keys: the source key, which is the user_id combined with a unique system id (possibly the country), and a surrogate key, which is a new generated key which has no bearing on any source system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's a terrible idea to inject logic into your primary key in this way. It really sets you up for failure - what if country A gets more than 4000000 user records?

There are a variety of solutions.

Ideally, you include the column "country" in all tables, and use that together with the ID as the primary key. This keeps the logic identical between master and country records.

If you're working with a legacy system, and cannot modify the country tables, but can modify the master table, add the key there, populate it during load, and use the combination of country and ID as the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

The way we handle this scenario in [Ajilius](http://ajilius.com/2016/08/enhancement-load-metadata-columns/) is to add metadata columns to the load. Values like SERVER_NAME or DATABASE_NAME might provide enough unique information to make a compound key unique.

An alternative scenario is to generate a GUID for each row at extract or load time, which would then uniquely identify each row.

The data vault guys like to use a hash across the row, but in this case it would only work if no row was ever a complete duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is why they made the Uniqueidentifier data type. See [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/uniqueidentifier-vs-identity).

If you can't change to that, I would put each one in a different table and then union them in a view. Something like:

```
create view vWorld
as
select 1 as CountryId, user_id
from SpainUsers
UNION ALL 
select 2 as CountryId, user_id
from USUsers
```

Answer (score -1):

Most efficient way to do this would be :-

```
If record from Country A, then user * 0 = Hence dwh_user_id = 0.

If record from Country B, then (user * 0)- 1 = Hence dwh_user_id = -1.

If record from Country C, then (user * 0)+ 1 = Hence dwh_user_id = 1.
```

Suggesting this logic assuming the dwh_user_id is supposed to be a number field.